# Dynamically Finding values grouped by subcategories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to see if there is an excel formula that allows me to do the following:

I have a company name and under each company name is the year not necessarily in order

[image: example of what I am looking to achieve]

I have tried many ways of thinking about it, but I can't overcome how to search on the same column with two criteria without just selecting the same 2019 number. Any help would be appreciated!!

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

This answer finds the "Company" in column A, establishes a range to the next "Company", then finds "2019" within that new range. Once found, it finds the value in column C. In the case of "2019 doesn't exist", it will return "-".

---

### Code

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(F6,A:A,0)+1+MATCH(2019,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(F6,A:A,0)+1&":A"&IFERROR(MATCH("Company*",INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(F6,A:A,0)+1&":A100"),0)+MATCH(F6,A:A,0)-1,10000)),0)-1),"-")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you provide, I think this is a simpler approach is isolate the search area and then just use vlookup,try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(2019,INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(E6,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($C:$C,IFERROR(MATCH(E7,$A:$A,0),100)),3,0),"")
```

[image]